# Convert lead to custom object in salesforce

Tags: salesforce

Can any one suggest me how to convert lead to custom object in salesforce?

We have an option to convert lead to account/contact/opportunity, but how to do for custom object?

Please share any code samples to achieve this?

Regards,
Rahini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create custom object records, the better way to do is to go with after update trigger which is fired on case and checks if 'isConverted' field is true in the trigger controller and you can proceed with the logic for creating custom object record.

```
trigger LeadTrigger on Lead (before update) 
{
    for(Lead lead : trigger.new) 
    {
        if (Lead.IsConverted)
        {
        // create custom object record.
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: I have converted lead to account and contacts. And from the lead details created new custom object. After this conversion, on again opening the lead page, it shows only converted account and contact name, how to add custom object name to this page?